# Copy instance of View - zoom doesn't work

Tags: view, copy, openlayers

I'd would pass copy of instance ol.View to map constructor. When I do that zoom stop working and I wonder why? 
I have to write some text to create post eh..

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.2.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <style>
    .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.2.0/build/ol.js"></script>
  <title>OpenLayers example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>My Map</h2>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    const copy = (obj) => {
      return Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)), obj);
    };

    const v = new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
      zoom: 4
    });
    
    var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
      view: copy(v)
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Openlayers v5.2.0

Comment: The view object contains functions, if bound to the old object they won't work as expected in a copy.  It works if you build a new view using the properties of the first.  `function copy(view) { return new ol.View(view.getProperties()); }`

Comment: @Mike Thanks mate!